# "Nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to use this code (from my last question (thanks Adam)),

```
bool AllDigitsIdentical(int number)
{
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        int digit = number % 10;
        if(digit != lastDigit)
            return false;
        number /= 10;
    }

    return true;
}
```

but the compiler just says in the second line at } :

```
Nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable
```

What can I do in my case? I have no plan…

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't happen to have something like:

```
- (void) someMethod
{

    bool AllDigitsIdentical(int number)
    {
        int lastDigit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        while(number > 0)
        {
            int digit = number % 10;
            if(digit != lastDigit)
                return false;
            number /= 10;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

That is, you have a function declared within a method's scope of implementation (though the same problem would occur for a function declared within a function).

In short, don't do that.  It isn't supported and the means via which GCC implements it is considered to be a bit of a security hole (IIRC).

Move it outside:

```
 bool AllDigitsIdentical(int number)
{
    int lastDigit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;
    while(number > 0)
    {
        int digit = number % 10;
        if(digit != lastDigit)
            return false;
        number /= 10;
     }

     return true;
}


- (void) someMethod
{

    .... call the function here ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this  function looks fine, is it possible you missed a closing `}`  in the code *before* this function ?

Comment: I´m sure that I didnt missed a closing } before the function.

Answer (score 0):

You probably pasted that into a method or into your main function! Make sure that that chuck of code is put OUTSIDE any other blocks of code.

so if you have main here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
     //blah
}
```

make sure that you put that code above or below it like so:

```
bool AllDigitsIdentical(int number){
    //blah
}
```

do NOT put it inbetween the { or } of the main function (or any other method)